# Установка php 5.6 в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ubuntu 16.04, при установке 5.6 выдаёт вот такую котлету. Куда рыть?

Comment: Мне нужна именно 5.6 версия php

Comment: ну, установлен у вас этот пакет. в чём проблема-то? p.s. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте так:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

и затем сама установка с предварительно установленным репозиторием

```
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php5.6
```

---

и ещё

```
a2enmod php5.6
```

Comment: Сделал всё тож самое, и всё равно та же ошибка...